# How to open hidden file input by clicking CSS :before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I've a hidden fileupload input and `:before` pseudo element. I'm trying to hide the input and open it by clicking the pseudo element.

But currently it's not when when i click the `:before`. How can i fix it?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="icon-buttonimage">
    <input name="my_image[]" id="my_file" size="27" type="file" class="inputImage" title="Upload images" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.icon-buttonimage:before {
    content:'\e800';
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 9px !important;
}
```

Also see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fq8G/1/)

Comment: Because you are clicking "before" that item. You need to click on the item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS :after pseudo element on INPUT field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

Comment: @Tuğrul the actual issue is that he isn't clicking before the *item*. he's clicking something else....

Comment: @LinkinTED as you can see from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14019758/2333214) (*more like a comment*) for the question you mentioned, pseudo elements work for some inputs in some browsers. It's not exactly a duplicate of that question...

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you've specified `::before` for the `<div>` containing the `input`. So clicking it won't trigger a click on the input.

Also applying `opacity:0` for the `input` won't work because it'll hide the pseudo elements as well.

You can do the following on `webkit` browsers (*tested in chorme and opera*)

- You can trigger the click by specifying `::before` for the `<input>`
- You can hide the `input` by setting `height` and `width` to `0` and display the `::before` alone by absolutely positioning it relative to the container div.

  ```
  div{
   position:relative;
  }
  input::before{
   content:'\e800';
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   /*Other styles*/
  }
  input {
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   outline:none; /*for hiding the selection around it once clicked*/
  }
  ```

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fq8G/3/)

*Side note: `:before` is css2 syntax, from css3 onwards it's `::before`*